# Execute Returning None with PostgreSQL in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, function

Here is my code

```
conn_string = "dbname=detector user=postgres password=1234 host=localhost port=5432"
print "Connecting to database\n    ->%s" % (conn_string)     
# get a connection, if a connect cannot be made an exception will be raised here
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
```

which it is outputting this, which seems to be ok.

```
Connecting to database
    ->dbname=detector user=postgres password=1234 host=localhost port=5432
```

I use this connection as `function(data, conn)`. 
Now, I noticed strange outputs with the test command:

```
_measurement_id = cursor.execute(
    'SELECT measurement_id FROM measurements ORDER BY time desc limit 1;'
);
```

which returns `None` through Python but inside `psql`, I get an integer. 
I think the mistake is in not using try-catch-except in creating the connection.

And if that is the problem, how can I pass a PostgreSQL connection to functions in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cursor.execute` doesn't return anything. You need to use `cursor.fetchone`, `cursor.fetchall`, or `for row in cursor:` after executing the query to retrieve the results.

```
cursor.execute("...")
_measurement_id = cursor.fetchone()
```

It has nothing to do with exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

try do this

```
try:
    cursor.execute(
    'SELECT measurement_id FROM measurements ORDER BY time desc limit 1;')
    _measurement_id = cursor.fetchone()
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    pass
finally:
    cursor.close()
```